# Is a comma after a verb and before an infinitive phrase acceptable?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, punctuation, infinitives, commas

Examples:

1. I strive, to get success to me.
2. The old man with a beer bottle ran, to learn to run without spilling.
3. An apple fell, to adhere to gravity.

---

If commas don't work can you recommend what I should use instead.  I want to make it clear that the 2nd to (used as a preposition) is only referring to the infinitive and not anything left of the comma.

Comment: None of your examples are "natural" (or even "credible") utterances, regardless of whether you include commas.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Why is that?

Comment: The second and third are very strange things to say, regardless of exactly how they're expressed in English. If I understand what you *mean* correctly, the first one could be phrased as *I strive to obtain success*, and the last as *An apple fell under the influence of gravity*. For the second one, perhaps *The old man ran with a beer bottle, [in order to] to learn to run without spilling*. You'd have to post each of them here *separately* to ask exactly why they're "unnatural" (but note that you'd have to show evidence of research, or they'd be closed as "proofreading").

Comment: @FumbleFingers The 2nd and 3rd examples were made up by me to illustrate my question.  The 1st example is the sentence which led me to ask this question.  So is the first example acceptable? (it can't be change to `I strive to obtain success` for my purpose in using it.)

Comment: @user58712 - "The *noun* *verbed*, to *other-verb*" means that the noun verbed *for the purpose of other-verbing*.  It sounds pretty weird to say that the apple fell for the purpose of adhering to gravity!

Comment: 1. `I strive in order to achieve success.` (We don't say "get success to me".) As for #3: `An apple fell because of gravity.` (We wouldn't use the preposition _to_ because, insofar as gravity is concerned, there isn't any motivation for the apple to fall, as @stangdon explains in a comment quite well.) You'll just have to take our word for it that, with or without the comma, your original sentences are very rough at best.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a standard use of a comma.

The basic uses of a comma include

- separating parallel elements of a series:

  > red, white, and blue
- apposition:

  > Marge, my mother's sister, was late

  but do not ordinarily include dividing a single phrase.

  In your three examples, the infinitive is a complement of the main verb and thus wouldn't be separated by a comma.

Comment: One commonly-seen piece of guidance is to use a comma where you would pause in speech. (I've seen several reputable websites debunk that as a "comma myth".) I wonder if that's where the OP got the notion that commas might be acceptable where they were put in the three sentences found in the question.

Comment: Quite possibly and I think that's a quasi-rule or perhaps better considered the opposite direction (pause when you see a comma)

Comment: @J.R. If you mean me by OP.  That's not why I ask.  I edited the question to answer your question.

Comment: what in mean in the main post about the uses of a comma or the quasi-rule I mentioned in my comma?

Comment: @eques Although unusual, would my usage off the comma be acceptable? And I don't understand what you mean by opposite rule.

Comment: opposite rule: comma implies a pause, not that a pause implies a comma. Besides your examples not being typical expressions even without the comma, it is not usual to put a comma between a verb and an infinitive complement

Comment: @user58712 - Too bad you didn't delve into those details more when you originally posted your question; you probably would have gotten more pointed answers. Anyhow, there is no need to use a comma to differentiate between an infinitive and a prepositional _to_; most natives will be able to figure out which is which simply by the context.

Comment: @J.R.  I agree but I'm not using this to speak to others, but rather to myself.  I'm using it for an affirmation, and affirmations are best when they can't be perceived in any other way.

Answer (score 1):

These commas are very much on the borderline of acceptability and I'd advise against them.

I'm not sure what you mean by "I want to make it clear that the 2nd *to* (used as a proposition) is only referring to the infinitive".

If what you mean is that "I strive, to get success" is **not** to be interpreted as meaning "I strive **in order to** get success", then actually the way to clarify this is to avoid the infinitive and write:

> I strive, [thus] getting [or gaining] success.

Similarly:

> The old man with a beer bottle ran, to learn to run without spilling.

If what you mean is that the man didn't run in order to learn to run without spilling, but rather that by (or while) running he learnt to run without spilling, you should say:

> The old man with a beer bottle ran, [thus] learning to run without spilling.

It sounds better with "thus" or "thereby" if the learning occurs as an unintentional by-product, or without "thus"/"thereby" if the learning is an intentional by-product.

> An apple fell, to adhere to gravity.

If what you mean is, not that the apple fell in order to adhere to gravity (which is an odd thought), but that the apple fell and thereby adhered to gravity, you should say:

> An apple fell, [thus] adhering to gravity.

Comment: I do mean I strive in order to get success.  I mean that the 2nd to only refers to words to the right side of the comma.

Comment: To say that you strive in order to get success, you simply say "I strive to get success" (though "gain" or "achieve" might be more idiomatic).  There's no need for a comma.